# Firebasestorage getFile not working with download url android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

```
val httpReference = firebaseStorageInstance.getReferenceFromUrl(dataModel.remoteFileUrl)

val localFile = FileHelper.getFileName(dataModel.fileName)
val file = File(localFile)
httpReference.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener {
    //Log
}.addOnFailureListener {
    //Log
}
```

My dataModel.remoteFileUrl is something like this "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app.appspot.com/o/testapp%2Ffiles%2Fnew_28_156403158_%20ticket%20.pdf?alt=media&token=066d143b-aa6a-4ab8-94b0"

This download Url is showing pdf file when opening it from browser but in Android with above code always hit onfailureListener with storage exception 
android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: "message": "Not Found.  Could not access bucket app.appspot.com"

Comment: It's dummy url. actual url is working in browser.